# Error when trying to send body in url query string parameter in implementation of Api Gateway publishing message to SNS

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway, amazon-sns

I am trying to carry out an implementation where through an interface in Api Gateway I publish a message on a SNS topic. But I am having certain drawbacks. When I try to send the message inside URL Query String Parameter in the following way
method.request.body operation stops working. But if I burn the message with a string like for example 'foo', it will work. In addition to that I would like to know if it is possible within the message to send the JSON of the body or if it could only be a plain text.

[Query String Parameter URL Parameter Listing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bvqhz.png)

Comment: Is this a `/GET` or a `/POST` request?

Comment: Also, if you want to send a message as a query parameter, you will have to encode it.